# Spring Security e Shiro -> Como autenticar um usuário no Security e passar um token para o Shiro

Tags: spring, autenticação, spring-security, token

Eu tenho dois aplicativos web: a primeira aplicação web está usando `Spring MVC` e Segurança e faz a autenticação do usuário no banco de dados. E funciona muito bem, obrigado.

A segunda `web-app` está usando `Shiro` para *login* de usuário em sua base de dados para conceder as autoridades e etc.

Pergunta: Como posso fazer o `login` no primeiro aplicativo com Security e passar o `token CSRF`, ou um outro, do `Spring Security` pro `shiro` e usá-lo para as suas necessidades?

Se você poderia me enviar um tutoriais ou exemplos disso, eu apreciaria.